# Property of first object in array being pushed but not second object

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, object

I'm working with an array, trying to create a function that determines which sites are available according to a given partySize and view, in other words which campsites are available that can fit the party size and have the given view. I am getting an output of 1 in my array, which is correct but it is not adding the number property for the second object in the campgrounds array.

The output in the array I am looking for with the current arguments is "[1,5]". I spent about 20 minutes messing with the code trying to find out what is going on. I tried changing some of my logic but it seems to be correct. Why exactly is the number for the second object not being pushed into the array? Thanks in advance!

```js
const campgrounds = [
  { number: 1, view: "ocean", partySize: 8, isReserved: false },
  { number: 5, view: "ocean", partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 12, view: "ocean", partySize: 4, isReserved: true },
  { number: 18, view: "forest", partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 23, view: "forest", partySize: 4, isReserved: true },
];

function findMyCampsites(campgrounds, view, partySize){
  let sites = []
  for (let i = 0; i < campgrounds.length; i++){
    if (campgrounds[i].isReserved === false && campgrounds[i].view === view.toLowerCase()
      && campgrounds[i].partySize >= partySize) {
        sites.push(campgrounds[i].number)
        return sites
    } else {
      return 'Sorry, no campsites with that view are available to host your party'
    }
  }
}
console.log(findMyCampsites(campgrounds, 'ocean', 4))
```

Comment: `else { return` will mean your function always returns after a single iteration of the loop. Let the loop finish first - or, even better, use `.filter` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that you are calling `return` within your [for statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for_statement)

Instead you should move it out:

```js
const campgrounds = [
  { number: 1, view: 'ocean', partySize: 8, isReserved: false },
  { number: 5, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 12, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: true },
  { number: 18, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 23, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: true },
];

function findMyCampsites(campgrounds, view, partySize) {
  const sites = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < campgrounds.length; i++) {
    if (
      campgrounds[i].isReserved === false &&
      campgrounds[i].view === view.toLowerCase() &&
      campgrounds[i].partySize >= partySize
    ) {
      sites.push(campgrounds[i].number);
    }
  }

  if (!sites.length) {
    return 'Sorry, no campsites with that view are available to host your party';
  }

  return sites;
}

const result = findMyCampsites(campgrounds, 'ocean', 4);

console.log(result);
```

Also, i would recommend a more functional solution using [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const campgrounds = [
  { number: 1, view: 'ocean', partySize: 8, isReserved: false },
  { number: 5, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 12, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: true },
  { number: 18, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 23, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: true },
]

const findMyCampsites = (campgrounds, view, partySize) => {
  const sites = campgrounds
    .filter(
      (s) =>
        s.isReserved === false &&
        s.view === view.toLowerCase() &&
        s.partySize >= partySize
    )
    .map(({ number: n }) => n)

  if (!sites.length) {
    return 'Sorry, no campsites with that view are available to host your party'
  }

  return sites
}

const result = findMyCampsites(campgrounds, 'ocean', 4)

console.log(result);
```